# AChartEngine Graph's View Empty Legend Area Wasted

Tags: android, achartengine

[image]

That orange area is also given to AchartEngine to draw its graph. Achartengine occupies that area for it's legend. But even i have done `dr.setShowLegend(false);` , achart does not occupy or adjust it's graph location according to that area. Also i can not shrink the graph view because the reason above, pie chart would also shrink. What i  ask is, is there any way to customize there (custom legend) or make pie fill up almost all area?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `setMargins`method to set Some margin of PieChart .

```
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {top, left, bottom, right});
```